# Bilinear map that is continuous on both variables is continuous

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X, Y$ be Banach spaces, $B: X \times Y \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ a bilinear map. I need to prove that If the bilinear function is continuous in both variables, then it is continuous.

For all $y \in Y $ we define $B_y(x)$ and similarly for all $x \in X$ we define $B_x(y).$ Let $B_y(x)$ be continuous for all $y\in Y$. It is thus bounded, i.e. $\forall y \,\,\exists M_y \geq 0$ with $|B_y(x)| \leq M_y \|x \|.$ Similarly, under the assumption that $B_x(y)$ is continuous, we conclude that it is bounded. Thus, $\forall x\,\, \exists M_x \geq 0$ with $|B_x(y)| \leq M_x \|x \|.$ By the uniform boundedness theorem, $\exists \,C \geq 0$ such that $\forall x \in X \,\,|B(x,y)|\leq C_1\|x\|.$ Similarly, $\forall y \in Y \,\,\, |B(x,y)|\,\leq C_2 \|y\|.$
Since continuity in both variables is assumed, I guess I must combine both of the inequalities. I need to get: $|B(x,y)| \leq C_1C_2 \| x\| \|y\|= C \| x\| \|y\|.$ But I do not know how to get that.

Can somebody provide any suggestion ? Thanks.

Comment: You application of the uniform boundedness is only valid for the family $\{B_y: \|y\| \le 1\}$.

Comment: Thanks. Why is this the case ?

Comment: The assumption of the uniform boundedness principle for a family $\{T_i: i\in I\}$ of continuous linear operators is that $\sup\{\|T_i(x)\|: i\in I\}$ is finite for every $x\in X$.

Comment: Sure. But since $T_i\,\, \forall i$ is bounded, the supremum will remain finite in case we took non-unit vectors, right ?

Comment: No, $\{B_y: y\in Y\}$ is not pointwise bounded. Consider, e.g., $B(x,y)=xy$for $X=Y=\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $|B_y(x) | \leq M_y \|x\|$. Think of $(B_y)_{y \in Y, \|y\|\leq 1}$ as a family of continuous linear maps on $X$. At each point $x\in X$ We have $\sup_y |B_y(x)| <\infty$. By Uniform Boundedness Principle this implies that $\sup \{|B(x,y)|:\|x\| \leq 1 , \|y\|\leq 1\} <\infty$. This implies continuity of $B(.,.)$.

Comment: Thanks. I have nevertheless a question. The boundedness of $B(x,y)$ is now clear. BUt since $B(x,y)$ is not linear ($B(\lambda x, \lambda y) = \lambda^2 B(x,y)$) rather then bilinear, how will we conclude the continuity from the boundedness? In case of linear operators this is straightforward. But in the present case we do not have the mere linearity.

Comment: @user996159 $B(x,y)=\|x\|\|y\|B(\frac x {\|x\|},\frac y {\|y\|})$ which gives $B(x,y) \leq M\|x\|\|y\|$. Continuity follows from this.